# Using Redis key as Elasticsearch index name

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I am attempting to use a logstash indexer to move data from redis to elasticsearch.

On the input to redis end, I give a 'key' to one set of logs from logstash output.

```
 redis
    {
    host           => "server
    port            => "7379"
    data_type       => "list"
    key             => "aruba"
    }
```

On input end , I read each keys in the input.

```
input
{
    redis
    {
        host        => "localhost"
        port        => "6379"
        data_type   => "list"
        type        => "redis-input"
        key         => "logstash"
        codec       => "json"
        threads     => 32
        batch_count => 1000
        #timeout     => 10
    }
    redis
    {
        host        => "localhost"
        port        => "6379"
        data_type   => "list"
        type        => "redis-input"
        key         => "aruba"
        codec       => "json"
        threads     => 32
        batch_count => 1000
        #timeout     => 10
    }
}
```

and I am attempting to use the key in the logstash to write to index. i.e.

aruba-2017.24.10. something like that, but the output always goes to logstash. I tried

```
if[redis.key] == "xyz"
{
    elasticsearch {index => "xyz-%{time}"}
}
```

or if[key] == "xyz" .... 
also tried

```
elasticsearch
{
    index => "%{key}-%{time}"
}
```

and elasticsearch{index => "%{redis.key}-%{time}"}

etc. None of it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @sysadmin1138 is write in that accessing nested fields is done via `[field][subfield]` rather than `[field.subfield]` your problem is that you are trying to access data that is not in your log event.

While in Redis, your log events have a key associated with them, but this is not part of the event itself and is merely used to access the event from Redis. When Logstash fetches the event from Redis, it uses that "key" to specify which events it wants, but the key does not make it to elastic.
To see this for yourself, try running logstash with `stdout{codec => "rubydebug"}` as an output plugin, it will prettyprint your whole log event allowing you to see what data is included.

To your rescue comes the `add_field` parameter that exists for every logstash plugin. You can add to your input:

```
redis
{
    host        => "localhost"
    port        => "6379"
    data_type   => "list"
    type        => "redis-input"
    key         => "aruba"
    codec       => "json"
    threads     => 32
    batch_count => 1000
    add_field   => {
      "[redis][key]" => "aruba"
    }
}
```

Then changing your conditional to use `[redis][key]` will leave your code working.

(Cheers to RELK stacks)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to an incorrect definition of the name in your conditional.

```
if [redis.key] == "xyz" {
    elasticsearch {index => "xyz-%{time}"}
}
```

Should be:

```
if [redis][key] == "xyz" {
    elasticsearch {index => "xyz-%{time}"}
}
```

Comment: Your answer along with Will Barnwell worked alright!